# Create a Table with data filtered from data in another worksheet

Tags: excel, filtering

I have a table with 105 columns and around 300 rows in Sheet 1. I need in Sheet 2 a reduced version of the same table, filtered by some column values (not the first column).

I've looked at Pivot Tables but it seems that I can not get the same tabular structure. I have tried with Advanced Filter and I get an error:

> "The extract range has a missing or illegal field name".

Could you help?

Comment: Show what you have done with advanced filter.  Can't tell what's wrong without seeing what you've done.

Comment: I have found the correct way of using Advanced filter. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that one needs to run Advanced Filter from the destination sheet, in an unused place (best over the intended destination, not on it or below it).

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a valid answer as you can't create the advanced filter output table in a different sheet than the source data.  The question specifically asks for the data output to be in a separate sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's PowerQuery addin supports this. One of its many sources can be Excel Data-From Table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [add-in for table-valued functions](http://finaquant.com/products/excel-add-in-for-table-valued-functions) I developed to make any operations (including filtering, partitioning, aggregation, distribution etc.) on data tables in Excel.

Each table (ListObject in Excel) is an input or output parameter for a table-valued function. You can for example feed three tables as input parameters to a table function which generates some resultant tables.